# storing equality and diversity data - is it normally encrypted?

Tags: encryption, databases

Is it the normative secure practice for databases storing E&D data (ethnicity, for example) on personally identifiable individuals? 
Assume a system where all other security features are also up to a high standard.

Is it to encrypt it or not?

Please note: I'm asking for the normative secure practice rather than best practice - what most individuals and organisations would consider secure.

Comment: GDPR has very specific guidance for this, and it is to encrypt, as well as other protections. It is an EU-centric regulation, of course.

Comment: @schroeder GDPR guidance would rather require not to store this data at all unless quite specific conditions permit doing so; I'd expect that more than half of organizations currently storing such data will have to delete it, not encrypt it.

Comment: If you want to put this in an answer (perhaps with a link to the appropriate section of the regulation) i'll mark it as the answer